# WPF WebBrowser: How to set element click event?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I've figured out how to make everything red as soon as the page is finished loading:

```
private void webBrowser1_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var doc = (IHTMLDocument2)webBrowser1.Document;
    foreach (IHTMLElement elem in doc.all)
    {
        elem.style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
    }
}
```

Now what if I want to make the element only change color when it's clicked? I see that `elem` has an `onclick` property, but it's type is `dynamic` so I don't know what to do with it. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752306%28VS.85%29.aspx) is pretty useless.

Comment: Uhm... CSS's :visited (http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pseudo_visited.asp) pseudo-class doesn't suit your needs, correct?

Comment: @Anvaka: No.... I want to handle the click event in C#.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it by using the `HTMLDocumentClass` instead of the `IHTMLDocument2` interface:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void webBrowser1_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass doc = (mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass)webBrowser1.Document;
        doc.HTMLDocumentEvents_Event_onclick += new mshtml.HTMLDocumentEvents_onclickEventHandler(OnClickHandler);
    }

    bool OnClickHandler()
    {
        mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass doc = (mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass)webBrowser1.Document;
        mshtml.IHTMLWindow2 win = doc.parentWindow;
        win.@event.srcElement.style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
        return false;
    }

}
```

The above solution, has one drawback: the `onclick` event does not bubble, even though `false` is returned (i.e. clicking at hyperlinks does not navigate to other pages).

Comment: I thought "true" was supposed to cause bubbling. And `HTMLDocumentClass` won't compile: "Interop type 'mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass' cannot be embedded. Use the applicable interface instead."

Comment: I have tested my code with VS2008 SP1 and .NET 3.5 SP1, and it works fine. Are you maybe using VS2010 and/or .NET 4? Then http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mshneer/archive/2009/12/07/interop-type-xxx-cannot-be-embedded-use-the-applicable-interface-instead.aspx might explain the reason why you are getting this error. In that case, you might try two things: 1) Do not embed Interop Types. OR: 2) Compile for .NET 3.5.